# ngIf after the DOM loaded

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm using angular 7 and materialize CSS.
When I use a directive like ngIf or ng, it looks like the javascript materialize framework does not find the DOM element and can not apply CSS.

Is there any way to defer policy enforcement?

```
 <div   class="carousel">
          <a *ngFor="let item of items" class="carousel-item"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>         
        </div>
```

Comment: If it's a css class and regular css that's from materialize, it shouldn't be a problem. Are you trying to set styles with javascript?

Comment: my code is just the html, it works if I put the hardcoded tags, but if I put the directive does not work. I noticed that as ngFor did not run yet, the css classes could not be applied by materialize

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the currency fell. I remembered the component lifecycle, looking at the angular documentation I found AfterViewInit and solved my problem.

https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit